# How to get GridFS file by UUID in new Mongo 2.X driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs, gridfs-stream

As we know, we can use ObjectId as our identifier. In my situation I have legacy code where we use GUIDs in MongoDB (UUID) as identifiers.

[Best Practices for UUID Data in MongoDB](http://3t.io/blog/best-practices-uuid-mongodb/)

I have a problem with getting a file from **GridFS** by **UUID**.

I use new **MongoDB.Driver.GridFS** package and use **GridFSBucket** class.

I would like to get stream by UUID not ObjectId but I can see that all overloads of DownloadToStream(XXX) methods have take **ObjectId** as parameter. There is no overload for **UUID**.

So, the question is:
Is there any way to convert safely UUID to ObjectId and try to get the file from MongoDB?

Any help will be appreciated.

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the GridFS spec requires that the id for a stored GridFS file be of type ObjectId.

But since there may be existing files stored in GridFS where the id is *not* an ObjectId, there is an overload of DownloadToStream that takes a BsonValue id.

Since there is no BSON type for GUID specifically, any GridFS files you might have where the id was originally a GUID would actually have the id stored as either a BsonBinary value or a BsonString value, depending on how you chose to represent the GUID in MongoDB.

So to read an existing GridFS file that was stored using a GUID as the id you need to convert that GUID to the appropriate BsonValue and then pass that BsonValue to the DownloadToStream overload that takes a BsonValue id.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert for you answer.

Yes, I have files stored in GridFS where id is not the ObjectId.

I did a little bit more research and I could find that there is an Obsolete attribute set for method DownloadToStreamAsync in GridFSBucket class, e.g.:

```
[Obsolete("All new GridFS files should use an ObjectId as the Id.")]
public Task DownloadToStreamAsync(BsonValue id, Stream destination, GridFSDownloadOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
```

I also could see that there is no related signature for that method in the IGridFSBucket interface, so that's the reason why I couldn't find that for the first time.

I used

```
private readonly GridFSBucket _gridFsBucket;
```

instead of using

```
private readonly IGridFSBucket _gridFsBucket;
```

so now it was possible to use the overloaded method and I could use GUID as appropriate BsonValue